# How can I identify test points in electrical circuits?

Tags: oscilloscope, testing

I have this circuit from an ECU that is malfunctioning.  I would like to diagnose the problem with an oscilloscope by probing the test points and comparing the signals with another identical ECU.

This is a picture of the ECU. I have drawn arrows on what I think are test points.

Am I correct?

[image]

Comment: Be very careful how you connect the grounding point of your oscilloscope probe. It will almost certainly be connected to mains earth and all the other probe earths. You must ensure that, whatever point you chose to connect it to is similarly at earth potential. Otherwise I predict the onset of magic smoke.

Comment: Yes, most likely; but they're more or less useless without full design docs/files. They're used for manufacturing test, and likely the assembly is meant to be discarded when failed -- no servicing or refurbishing. If you don't have files, then you can trace the circuit to some extent, and maybe find things in error, but it's a LOT of guesswork.

Comment: On a related note: ooh, I'd be willing to bet that unpopulated 2x5 SMT header is a JTAG port or something. Which, again, not that that's necessarily going to help you much without the firmware this thing runs -- but it makes reverse engineering or reprogramming slightly easier, at least.

Comment: @TimWilliams if any device class has heavily locked down debug ports, it's ECUs ;)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Indeed, just another of many mysteries to consider on something like this :)

Answer (score 1):

These do look indeed like test points.

If you have access to another identical ECU, wyh don't you scrap the one you're working on? An ECU is a very locked-down, complex devices. Unless you have an easy-to-repair fault in a power supply which, by sheer luck, hasn't damaged anything else, it'll be very unlikely that you find something you *can* repair. What are you going to do? Replace a microcontroller and somehow extract the correct firmware from the clone-protected broken one?

Comment: There is a driver IC that I'm suspecting having the problem, also the capacitors can be faulty. Can I know if the capacitors are faulty through those test points though?

Comment: that's unlikely. You can only observe a voltage through a test point. Say your reference board has 1.18V on a test point. Yours has 1.14 V. Whether that is normal, a problem with the reference voltage of some unknown regulator, or a badly damaged capacitor loading the supply – you can never know.

Comment: The most common failure is solder  contact on new boards

Comment: but seeing that OP has a malfunctioning ECU with potting residue, and relatively low component density, I'd say we're not dealing with a new board by any means, @TonyStewartEE75.

Comment: True but unless they did vibration during test, escapes are still possible. And only likely possible fix for him

Comment: @MarcusMüller If I found there is a difference in voltage signal will that at least narrow down where to look for the problem on the PCB? I assume every test point has some specific components connected to it?

Comment: hm, no without knowing what OK ranges for these test points are, only crass differences help as indication. Really, I don't think this will take you anywhere. ECUs were simply not designed to be serviced.